# Confusment with 'this' scope

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The following code:

```
define(function () {

var Module = function() {

    $('.fixed-sidebar').each( function( index ) {
        FixedSidebar.apply( this );
    });

}

var FixedSidebar = function() {
    var me = this;
    this.hiddenStatus = true;
    console.log ( this.toggle );

    $($(this).find('.fixed-handler')).on('click', function() {
        console.log('event passed');
        //me.toggle();
        //console.log ( this );
    });
}

FixedSidebar.prototype = {
    constructor : FixedSidebar
    ,toggle : function() {

             if( this.hiddenStatus ) {
                this.hiddenStatus = false;
                $('.fixed-sidebar').animate( {
                    left: '-300px'
                }, 1000);
             } else {
                this.hiddenStatus = true;
                $('.fixed-sidebar').animate( {
                    left: '0px'
                }, 1000);
             }

    }
};

return Module;
});
```

any idea why JavaScript is not prototyping the 'toggle' method in the following moment ?

```
console.log ( this.toggle ); // undefined
```

Comment: please define, 'define'

Comment: a requirejs module definition

Comment: `define` is a function, where is it defined?

Comment: I see. Added relevant tags.

Comment: Do you get any erros?

Comment: define is a requireJS AMD module - we can treat it as a closure - but this shouldn't affect on my issue

Comment: I want to know why on the following code 'console.log ( this.toggle );' the 'toggle' method is not prototyped - as I think it should be, due to the prototype code block

Comment: No errors - just 'undefined'

Comment: @OskarSzura well you call `FixedSidebar.apply( this );` which just invokes the function in the context of the element. But you never create on object of `FixedSidebar`, `this` refers to the DOMElement object.

Comment: @t.niese - well, this it it! :) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem it that you call the `FixedSidebar` function with `apply(this)`. This will change the `this` in the function to the DOM object that was clicked. A better way would be to call the function with `new`,  so  `this` will be the new created function object that will have the toggle function in its prototype, and pass the DOM object as function parameter into the constructor function.

```
define(function () {

  var Module = function () {

    $('.fixed-sidebar').each(function (index) {
      new FixedSidebar(this);
    });

  }

  var FixedSidebar = function (element) {
    var me = this;
    this.hiddenStatus = true;
    console.log(this.toggle);

    $($(element).find('.fixed-handler')).on('click', function () {
      console.log('event passed');
      //me.toggle();
      //console.log ( this );
    });
  }

  FixedSidebar.prototype = {
    constructor: FixedSidebar,
    toggle: function () {

      if (this.hiddenStatus) {
        this.hiddenStatus = false;
        $('.fixed-sidebar').animate({
          left: '-300px'
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        this.hiddenStatus = true;
        $('.fixed-sidebar').animate({
          left: '0px'
        }, 1000);
      }

    }
  };

  return Module;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call this way :

```
FixedSidebar.apply( this );
```

You pass the window object with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) & hence *this* refers to the same window object later.

Rather initialize it as `new FixedSidebar()`

---

*Note:* In the above context this is a DOM element.

Comment: If `$` is jQuery, what i assume, then `this` is the `DOMElement`

Comment: @t.niese - You are correct, it's no the window object. 'this' has never been mentioned as it would be placed in the global scope.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, you are right about that. In the above context it's DOM

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var FixedSidebar = function() {
    var me = this;
    me.hiddenStatus = true;
    console.log ( me.toggle() );

    $($(this).find('.fixed-handler')).on('click', function() {
        console.log('event passed');
        //me.toggle();
        //console.log ( this );
    });
}

FixedSidebar.prototype = {
    var _this = this;
    constructor : FixedSidebar,
    toggle : function() {

             if( _this.hiddenStatus ) {
                _this.hiddenStatus = false;
                $('.fixed-sidebar').animate( {
                    left: '-300px'
                }, 1000);
             } else {
                _this.hiddenStatus = true;
                $('.fixed-sidebar').animate( {
                    left: '0px'
                }, 1000);
             }

    }
};
```

Comment: well `me.toggle` will be still `undefined`, and therefore it will fail with an error like `undefined is not a function`